# Frequency table using dplyr package

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new to R.I want to create a new frequency column based on a particular column.

```
City    age
ABC     47
AAB     48
AAB     41
AAB     984
ZZZ     984
MNO      1
MNO     34
VVC     34
VVC     36
VVC     41
VVC     32
MNO     20
BB      29
VVC     4
VVC    984
VVC     59
ABC     30
ABC    984
ABC     36
BB      69
ABC     32
ZZZ     3
ABC     29
ABC     29
AAB     1
AAB     984
ABC     59
```

I want data frame looks like -

```
City    age     Frequency
ABC     47      0.296296296
AAB     48      0.185185185
AAB     41      0.185185185
AAB     984     0.185185185
ZZZ     984     0.074074074
MNO     1       0.111111111
MNO     34      0.111111111
VVC     34      0.259259259
VVC     36      0.259259259
VVC     41      0.259259259
VVC     32      0.259259259
MNO     20      0.111111111
BB      29      0.074074074
VVC     4       0.259259259
VVC     984     0.259259259
VVC     59      0.259259259
ABC     30      0.296296296
ABC     984     0.296296296
ABC     36      0.296296296
BB      69      0.074074074
ABC     32      0.296296296
ZZZ     3       0.074074074
ABC     29      0.296296296
ABC     29      0.296296296
AAB     1       0.185185185
AAB     984     0.185185185
ABC     59      0.296296296
```

In frequency column, I used this formula -

```
ABC   8             0.296296296 (8/27)
MNO   3             0.111111111 (3/27)
BB    2             0.074074074 (2/27)
VVC   7             0.259259259 (7/27)
ZZZ   2             0.074074074 (2/27)
AAB   5             0.185185185 (5/27)
```

You can ignore 'Age' column. How to do it in R?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 3):

After grouping by 'City', create the 'Frequency' by dividing the number of rows (`n()`) with the number of rows of the whole dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(City) %>%
    mutate(Frequency = n()/nrow(.))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. But in this data frame where it stored ('Frequency' column)?

Comment: `mutate` creates new column Frequency